# C float or double in printf format specifier and pow function

Tags: c, printf, double, pow, specifier

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void){

   printf("%lf\n", pow(1.0, 2.0));
   printf("%f\n", pow(1.0, 2.0));

   return 0;    
}
```

First `printf()` gives output `0.000000` but second `printf()` gives output `1.000000`. Why?

Using Codeblocks on Windows 7 64 bit.

Using gcc command to compile give me an .exe that outputs 1.000000 for both statements.

If I compile pressing F9 on Codeblocks, I get 0.000000 for the first statement and 1.000000 for the second.

Finally, if I remove `#include <stdio.h>` from source code in Codeblocks, all give me 1.000000 (no warnings or errors).

Comment: Not on ideone: https://ideone.com/SRmfgd

Comment: For [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) it should not matter, `"%f"` and `"%lf"` are equal as both expect a `double` argument. Is the code you're showing the *actual* code you have tested with? Please create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and then copy-paste it into the question.

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: How exactly are you compiling?

Comment: Updated my code, compiling from Codeblocks pressing F9

Comment: I ran it on Codeblocks on Windows 10 64-bit and got output 1.000000 for both `printf()` https://imgur.com/a/iYo5p

Comment: code::blocks is not a compiler

Comment: Using gcc command to compile give me an .exe that outputs 1.000000  for both statements.
if I compile pressing F9 on Codeblocks, I get 0.000000 for the first statement and 1.000000 for the second.
Finally, if I remove #include <stdio.h> from source code in Codeblocks, all give me 1.000000.

Comment: Which compiler does CodeBlocks use?

Comment: I see "Cygwin gcc"

Answer (score 4):

Your code should print the same value for both lines on a C99 or C11 compiler. All `float` arguments to `printf` are always converted to `double`, and `%lf` and `%f` both do the same thing (print a `double`).

In the C89 standard, the `%lf` specifier is undefined behavior and `double`s should only be printed with `%f`. So perhaps you're using an old compiler which doesn't support the C99 standard.

Relevant sections of the standards regarding `%lf`:

C99, 7.19.6.1/7:

> l (ell)  [...]  has no effect on a following a, A, e, E, f, F, g,or G conversion speciﬁer.

C89, 4.9.6.1:

> [...]  an optional l (ell) specifying that a following d , i , o , u , x , or X conversion specifier applies to a long int or unsigned long int argument; an optional l specifying that a following n conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a long int argument; [...]  If an h , l , or L appears with any other conversion specifier, the behavior is undefined.